# empty cells in accessible html tables

Tags: accessibility, html, tables

For an html data table in which each row represents an item (such as an email) would screen-reader users prefer empty table cells to be empty or to have a placeholder like a dash?

In my brief experience I think a dash would be useful because it keeps navigation consistent among the rows, but I want to make sure that this intuition is correct.

Comment: Maybe put in 'Not Applicable' in the empty cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JAWS will read an empty cell as "BLANK" [as noted here](http://www.usability.com.au/resources/tables.cfm), which is why it's a good idea to avoid lots of empty cells (and table based BLANK layouts BLANK). Placing a dash will cause it to read the dash as well, which would make a lot less sense than BLANK.

I *believe* JAWS will also read a table cell with `&nbsp;` inside as BLANK but I can't test this. [It seems to read such elements as BLANK](http://www.accessifyforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=1682).

If the table is proper tabular data laid out correctly, BLANK is the logical way to read a blank row.

Also note if you leave a dash in an empty table cell it might make less sense to sighted users too. What does a dash mean for "Mother's Maiden Name"* for instance?

<sub>*Aside from Le Dasha</sub>